# Load an XML string into a Vaadin Tree

Tags: xml-parsing, treeview, vaadin, hierarchical-data

I am doing a project in Vaadin and need to do the following. I make a server request and get an XML string in response. And, I know nothing about how this XML file will look at run time. I need to convert this XML  string into a vaadin tree.

I have seen some answers where they say to load into a HierarchicalContainer and all but I'm unable to make sense of it.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use HierarchicalContainer (I have no experience with that), you can just parse the XML document recursively like that: [Recursive XML-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295621/recursive-xml-parser)

Then just add the items and set the parent. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    setContent(tree);       
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\temp\\sample.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Object rootItem = root.getNodeName();
        tree.addItem(rootItem);
        addChildrenToTree(tree, root.getChildNodes(), rootItem);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}

private void addChildrenToTree(Tree tree, NodeList children, Object parent) {
    if (children.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = children.item(i);
            Object child = node.getNodeName();
            tree.addItem(child);
            tree.setParent(child, parent);
            addChildrenToTree(tree, node.getChildNodes(), child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, generally my last xml element in a particular tree is of the form <foo>bar</foo>. Now, I want to put bar as the child of foo. foo doesn't have any other children. I added this code to the else of the if in addChildrenToTree

`tree.addItem(parent.getTextContent());
tree.setParent(parent.getTextContent(), parent.getNodeName());`

And yeah, I pass parent as an Element and not as a String. Please help :)

Comment: Looks like the value is also considered a node so try if (children.getLength() > 1) {...} else {<what you posted>}